# CCD vs CDA training

Tags: ccd, hl7-cda, hl7-v3, c-cda

Does anyone know of any good training for CDA/CCD besides the one offered by HL7?

If you know of any places that offer training or even good books on the subject please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"The CDA (tm) Book" written by Keith Boone is a kind of HL7 CDA R2 Bible. 
Take a look at the Keith's blog http://motorcycleguy.blogspot.com.
Eclipse instance editor is the best tool for CDA learning and research. It comes with a lot of sample documents

Comment: I second Keith's CDA book and blog. Another great resource is the IHE PCC Implementers google group: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/ihe-pcc-implementors

Comment: I know this is old, but do you have a link to the "Eclipse instance editor" you are talking about?

Comment: Instance editor was previously available at http://cdatools.org. I have a distributive but it can be outdated. You can get it here <https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=5E369A744D0F049!4753&authkey=!ABdcimSO_aOwVI4&ithint=file%2cexe>